# iOS - open word document page by page

Tags: ios, ms-word, swift2, ms-office

I need to develop an app to open a word (and pdf) document and see it "as a magazine".

I can open them in a UIWebView, but I dont know how to see just a page so I can add some button to go to other pages.

Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: see this link , it helps you http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130

Comment: thx @Anbu.Karthik I tried that but i cannot find how to control the page: get the actual page or go to some page

Comment: One problem with what you want to do is that internally, a Word document doesn't have the concept of "pages" - unless Ctrl+Enter (forced page break) has been used. Word calculates the text flow dynamically to display "pages" in the Word application and when sending the document to the printer. But the application interface is required for that. The document stores no information about page breaks (or at least none that's reliable). You'd need to code how to calculate "pages" or find some tool that can do this for you.

Comment: thx @CindyMeister that is sad, so you know if a pdf has the same problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure PDF "hard-codes" the page breaks, but my knowledge about that file format pretty much ends there :-)